# Декомпрессия данных в Qt

Tags: qt, gzip, deflate, zlib

Бинарные данные от сокетов приходят в сжатом виде по сигналу:

```
QWebSocket::binaryMessageReceived
```

Сокеты разные, алгоритмы сжатия данных тоже разные. 
Для одних подходит функция:

```
bool RequestSender::gzipDecompress(const QByteArray &input, QByteArray &output)
{
    // Prepare output
    output.clear();

    // Is there something to do?
    if(input.length() > 0)
    {
        // Prepare inflater status
        z_stream strm;
        strm.zalloc = nullptr;
        strm.zfree = nullptr;
        strm.opaque = nullptr;
        strm.avail_in = 0;
        strm.next_in = nullptr;

        // Initialize inflater
        int ret = inflateInit2(&strm, GZIP_WINDOWS_BIT);

        if (ret != Z_OK)
            return(false);

        // Extract pointer to input data
        const char *input_data = input.data();
        int input_data_left = input.length();

        // Decompress data until available
        do {
            // Determine current chunk size
            int chunk_size = qMin(GZIP_CHUNK_SIZE, input_data_left);

            // Check for termination
            if(chunk_size <= 0)
                break;

            // Set inflater references
            strm.next_in = (unsigned char*)input_data;
            strm.avail_in = chunk_size;

            // Update interval variables
            input_data += chunk_size;
            input_data_left -= chunk_size;

            // Inflate chunk and cumulate output
            do {

                // Declare vars
                char out[GZIP_CHUNK_SIZE];

                // Set inflater references
                strm.next_out = (unsigned char*)out;
                strm.avail_out = GZIP_CHUNK_SIZE;

                // Try to inflate chunk
                ret = inflate(&strm, Z_NO_FLUSH);

                switch (ret) {
                case Z_NEED_DICT:
                    ret = Z_DATA_ERROR;
                case Z_DATA_ERROR:
                case Z_MEM_ERROR:
                case Z_STREAM_ERROR:
                    // Clean-up
                    inflateEnd(&strm);

                    // Return
                    return(false);
                }

                // Determine decompressed size
                int have = (GZIP_CHUNK_SIZE - strm.avail_out);

                // Cumulate result
                if(have > 0)
                    output.append((char*)out, have);

            } while (strm.avail_out == 0);

        } while (ret != Z_STREAM_END);

        // Clean-up
        inflateEnd(&strm);

        // Return
        return (ret == Z_STREAM_END);
    }
    else
        return(true);
}
```

Для других такая:

```
int RequestSender::gzdecompress(Byte *zdata, uLong nzdata, Byte *data, uLong *ndata)
{
    int err = 0;
    z_stream d_stream = {0}; /* decompression stream */

    static char dummy_head[2] = {
        0x8 + 0x7 * 0x10,
        (((0x8 + 0x7 * 0x10) * 0x100 + 30) / 31 * 31) & 0xFF,
    };

    d_stream.zalloc = NULL;
    d_stream.zfree = NULL;
    d_stream.opaque = NULL;
    d_stream.next_in = zdata;
    d_stream.avail_in = 0;
    d_stream.next_out = data;

    if (inflateInit2(&d_stream, -MAX_WBITS) != Z_OK) {
        return -1;
    }

    // if(inflateInit2(&d_stream, 47) != Z_OK) return -1;

    while (d_stream.total_out < *ndata && d_stream.total_in < nzdata) {
        d_stream.avail_in = d_stream.avail_out = 1; /* force small buffers */
        if((err = inflate(&d_stream, Z_NO_FLUSH)) == Z_STREAM_END)
            break;

        if (err != Z_OK) {
            if (err == Z_DATA_ERROR) {
                d_stream.next_in = (Bytef*) dummy_head;
                d_stream.avail_in = sizeof(dummy_head);
                if((err = inflate(&d_stream, Z_NO_FLUSH)) != Z_OK) {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (inflateEnd(&d_stream)!= Z_OK)
        return -1;
    *ndata = d_stream.total_out;
    return 0;
}
```

Но обнаружил еще третий сокет, который использует совсем иной алгоритм сжатия и две эти функции не работают. В документации указано https://www.okex.com/docs/en/#spot_ws-general `All the messages returning from Websocket API are optimized by Deflate compression.`

На гитхабе достаточно декомпрессоров, и сигнатуры функций у них похожи. Но увы, я не понимаю, какие входные параметры нужно задавать.

Как нужно инициализировать структуру и что передавать в функцию in/out, чтобы получить данные?

Comment: что именно непонятно? обе функции на вскидку одинаковые, хотя обе и написаны несколько по-дурацки... особенно вторая.... по поводу ошибки — смотри где и какая ошибка возникает — может ты просто не полностью полученное сообщение пытаешься расшифровать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer функции взяты на просторах интернета. самому не нравятся, но работают. мне не понятно, почему именно такие значения для инициализации и откуда их брать? так же не понимаю, как передать входные данные. если в первую функцию мы передаем сжатые данные и получаем результат в ``output``. То что передавать во вторую? и как инициализировать ее?

Comment: Во вторую передавать — тоже самое, что и в первую: `zdata` — входные данные, `nzdata` — их размер, `data` и `ndata` — соответственно выходные и их размер... с инициализацией: ты про что? про инициализацию потоков (`strm`/`d_stream`)? там вроде всё довольно очевидно, но можешь какой-нить букварь/ghbvths по zlib посмотреть...